# Trying to use XSLT to change account and pass in AdMemberShipProvider in app config... looks correct but it's not working

Tags: .net, xslt

Give this in a app config:

```
  <system.web>
    <membership defaultProvider="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="MyADMembershipProvider" 
             type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" 
             connectionStringName="ADConnectionString" 
             connectionUsername="XXXXXXX" 
             connectionPassword="YYYYYYY" 
             attributeMapUsername="SAMAccountName" 
             />
        <add name="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientFormsAuthenticationMembershipProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri="" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
```

And this xslt transform:

```
  <xsl:template match="/configuration/system.web/membership/providers/add[@name='MyADMembershipProvider']/@connectionUsername" >
    <xsl:attribute name="connectionUsername">
      <xsl:text>TestUser</xsl:text>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
```

Can anyone please tell me why XXXXXXX is not getting Replaced wtih TestUser? the rest of my simple XSLT swaps are working as I'd expect.

For some reason the two like this don't work.

I'm using the .Net xslt engine.

Thanks,

Cal-

Comment: Any reason you are not using [web config transforms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465318.aspx)?

Comment: I'm trying to use the same tool that's being used elsewhere in our Buidl process. Single tool, reuse markup, That's the only reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, you wish to copy all but change the connectionUserName attribute value. That can be achieved by below transformation.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates  select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@connectionUsername">
        <xsl:attribute name="connectionUsername">TestUser</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Do add an end tag `</system.web>` to your input xml though.

**EDITED**

On request, I changed the match attribute value in the template, in order to only update connectionUserName attribute for specific add elements.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates  select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@connectionUsername[../@name='MyADMembershipProvider']">
        <xsl:attribute name="connectionUsername">TestUser</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I guess you are missing those conditions mentioned in his original code.

Comment: You guessed right and since that was obvious I thought I'd leave it like that. But now that both you and Dimitre make this point, I will edit my answer.

Comment: Rememebr what's obvious to you isn't obvious to others, espeically if they are asking for help on the subject. weird unwanted side effects are unhelpful. Thanks for fixing it though, as the revised answer was the most useful of all 4 provided.

Comment: You're right! And - lucky me - although we all said the same but in different wordings and with a different level of testing the node to be changed :-)

Answer (score 1):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="add[@name = 'MyADMembershipProvider']">
  <add connectionUsername="TestUser">
   <xsl:apply-templates select=
   "@*[not(name()='connectionUsername')]
   | node()
   "/>
  </add>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied on the provided XML document (wrapped in a `configuration` element):

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <membership defaultProvider="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider">
            <providers>
                <add name="MyADMembershipProvider"
                  type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
                  connectionStringName="ADConnectionString"
                  connectionUsername="XXXXXXX"
                  connectionPassword="YYYYYYY"
                  attributeMapUsername="SAMAccountName"
                />
                <add name="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider"
                type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientFormsAuthenticationMembershipProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
                serviceUri="" />
            </providers>
        </membership>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result** (the `connectionUsername` attrinute changed to `"TestUser"`):

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <membership defaultProvider="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider">
         <providers>
            <add connectionUsername="TestUser" name="MyADMembershipProvider"
            type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
            connectionStringName="ADConnectionString"
            connectionPassword="YYYYYYY"
            attributeMapUsername="SAMAccountName"/>
            <add name="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider"
            type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientFormsAuthenticationMembershipProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
            serviceUri=""/>
         </providers>
      </membership>
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

**Do note**:

1. No `xsl:attribute` is used at all.
2. The template pattern of the template that overrides the **[identity rule](http://dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html)**, includes more contextual information -- in order to avoid the case when all `connectionUsername` attributes on all `add` elements are modified to have the same value of `"TestUser"` -- as this would happen with the other provided answer to this question.

Comment: This worked when i tested it, but when i added antoehr one to update the password, it rewrote the password stomping the username, so I went with Maistros revised answer which had the fewest side effects, Thanks for al the help, I over simplified my question totaly not anyoes fault!

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="//membership/providers/add[@name='MyADMembershipProvider']/@connectionUsername" >
    <xsl:attribute name="connectionUsername">
      <xsl:text>TestUser</xsl:text>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I guess XPath-hierarchy isn't perfect .. because XPath in your XSL code is like

```
/configuration/system.web/membership/providers/add
```

and the root node in your sample XML is

```
<system.web>
```

Comment: When i tried this answer it did not work in my applicaiton nothgni happened, so I went with maestros revised answer. Thanks for nudging him to revise it.

Comment: @EricBrown-Cal, ah! then its definitely mistake with your XPath. Glad it could work anyways :)